# Is DispatchQueue.global(qos: qos.qosClass).async allot slower in Swift3?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, swift3

I am toying around with Swift 3, and dispatch_async was changed.

**Previously I used :**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
    // Do stuff
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
         // Do stuff
    }
}
```

**And in Swift 3 I use:**

```
let qos = DispatchQoS.init(qosClass: .userInteractive, relativePriority: 0)
DispatchQueue.global(qos: qos.qosClass).async {
    // Do stuff
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

I have the feeling it is allot slower than how it worked in Swift 2. 
Some tasks take up to 7 seconds, previously it took only 1.
For example counting all the photos of the users device

*In the docs, qosClass .userInteractive is the fasted way to excecute a task. 
(table 4.1 on https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/PrioritizeWorkWithQoS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015243-CH39-SW9)*

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it just... slower?

**TLDR;**
Swift 3 async task slower?